# Можно ли как-то сократить этот код? PHP

Tags: php

```
            if ($weather['main'] == "Clouds"){
        
                $weather['main'] = "Облачно. ";
                
            } else if ($weather['main'] == "Rain"){
                
                $weather['main'] = "Ожидается дождь! ";
                
            } else if ($weather['main'] == "Snow"){
                
                $weather['main'] = "Будет снег! ";
                
            } else if ($weather['main'] == "Extreme"){
                
                $weather['main'] = "Погода просто сумасшедшая, оставайтесь дома! ";
                
            } else {
                
                $weather['main'] = "Ясная погода. ";
                
            }
```

Comment: или использовать switch()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$map = ['Clouds' => 'ОБлачно', 'Rain' => 'Дождь', ...];
echo $map[$weather['main']];
```

C ясной погодой можно решить по-разному. Либо пустая строка в виде ключа будет заменять её. Либо лишний if всё же придётся написать в начале. Рекомендую для единообразия первый вариант. Либо  для ясной погоды тоже сделать alias, как и для всех. Тогда будет проще

Comment: Спасибо спасибо

Answer (score 0):

По простому можно использовать массивы, и получится что-то вот такое:

```
$array = [
    'Clouds' => "Облачно.",
    'Rain' => "Ожидается дождь!",
    'Snow' => "Будет снег!",
    'Extreme' => "Погода просто сумасшедшая, оставайтесь дома!"
];
if (isset($array[$weather['main']])){
    echo $array[$weather['main']];
}else{
    echo 'Ясная погода.';
}
```

Comment: Спасибо спасибо